# Do I need a seperate application ID to integrate with each customer's Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I work on a SaaS application and we are working with a number of customers to provide them with a Single Sign-On experience via OpenID Connect. Many of our customers use (Azure) Active Directory.

I have registered an "application ID" for our app in our own Azure account (in the "Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps" blade), and have a client id and secret. I have configured the application for the "common" tenant, which is apparently for:

> Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and
> personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)
>
> All users with a work or school, or personal Microsoft account can use your application or
> API. This includes Office 365 subscribers

However, when one of our customers tried a test version, they received the error:

> Administrator approval required
>
> $OUR_APP needs authorization to access the resources of your organization, and
> this access can only be authorized by an administrator.

When I contacted their IT department, they instead provided me with a different application ID and client secret that they apparently registered with their directory. This works, but
it seems like it will be alot of registrations to maintain in the long term.

Will this be neccessary for each customer? Or can I ask the customers to approve our existing application id instead? What is the "normal" process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't require separate application id and your single application supports multi tenant if you are using "common" endpoint.This error occurs because the user doesn't have permissions to use this application.

The easiest way to allow users to access application  is by enable user access to Enterprise apps. From your Admin portal, go to `Admin Centers > Azure AD > Users and Groups > User Settings` then make sure "**Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf**" is **enabled**.

If this option is set to **yes**, then non-admin users may register custom-developed applications for use within this directory. If this option is set to no, then only users with an administrator role may register these types of applications.

Comment: Thanks! But for organizations that don't want to set this option to yes, how does an administrator register our application?

Comment: Found the answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent

Comment: Hi, @akbertram,Thank you for the update and you are going in right path.